# How to declare a const reference to function type

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

void func()
{

}

int main()
{
  using T = const decltype(func) &;
  using T2 = void (&)();
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same_v<T, T2> << std::endl;
}
```

How do you declare a `const reference` to a function type? The statement above prints `true` so I'm assuming that the `const` in `T` is ignored somehow. Is it possible at all to declare a `const reference` to a function type?

Comment: Functions are compile-time things, so they are constant anyway.

Comment: this is semantics. I was only asking from syntactic point of view if such a thing is possible

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[[dcl.fct]p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#7):

> The effect of a *cv-qualifier-seq* in a function declarator is not the same as adding cv-qualification on top of the function type. In the latter case, the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

So you can only have a reference to a function, but not a `const&` as the `const` on a function type is ignored, as per above.

Comment: Thanks was looking for something decisive as such statement on cppreference but couldn't find. But what is meant by `The effect of a cv-qualifier-seq in a function declarator `?

Comment: @mkmostafa It says that `const T` where `T` is a function type is not the same as having a `void f() const`, where the `const` is at the end. With *effect* they mean what the meaning of that thing is.

Comment: @mkmostafa First sentence in [cppref for cv qualifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) under "Explanation".

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The second case applies only to member functions

Answer (score 13):

First of all, *all references are constant*. Once a reference has been initialized and bound to an object, it cannot be bound to another object. The reference is constant.

When we talk about "const reference", this in fact means a reference to a const object.

> Is it possible at all to declare a const reference to a function type?

What does it mean for a free function to be const ? Nothing. Only non-static member functions can be const. No, it is not possible to have a reference to a constant function. Better yet, that `const` qualifier is ignored by the compiler, for good reason.

Comment: >  `all references are constant`

that is not my question, I know you can't reset an initialized reference. I meant reference to const.

> `What does it mean for a free function to be const ? Nothing`

this is semantics, I was asking from syntactic point of view if you can declare it not for the reason behind it begin ignored.

Comment: @mkmostafa Well the reason is that it has no effect :)

Comment: @mkmostafa This is not your question, but this is a pre-condition to my answer. Explicit > implicit.

Comment: Finally, I did answer your question: "that const qualifier is ignored by the compiler". And giving the reason why is a free bonus.